# Convert arabic numerals in roman numerals in pure CSS

Tags: html, css, roman-numerals, css-content, css-counter

I'm writing a custom theme for a website, so I cannot use Javascript. I would like to **convert some numbers to roman numerals**.

I tried this:

```css
.score:before {
  counter-reset: mycounter attr(score number, 0);
  content: counter(mycounter, upper-roman) " ";
}
```

```html
 <p><span class="score" score="11">points</span></p>
```

Alas, it seems that "attr(score number, 0)" is always 0. It's not because of a fallback, since when I change the fallback number to 42, the result stays 0. It's not a problem somewhere else in the code, because it works fine when I replace `attr(...)` by a number like 42.

So why isn't this code showing what it should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even today, `attr()` is still only supported for `content:` usage, not for anything else, as you can see from all the red flags here: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-attr

*Screenshot:*

[image: caniuse-attr]

Comment: I think this is the main blocker. I'm marking your response as accepted now, but if someone has a genius idea on how I could hack my way in pure CSS without needing this feature, it would be awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You can use var to pass proper values to your css files and counter, for example:

```css
.score {
   counter-increment: my-awesome-counter 0;
   counter-reset: my-awesome-counter var(--data-score);
}

.score:before {
  content: counter(my-awesome-counter, upper-roman);
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p><span style="--data-score:11" class="score" score='11'>points</span></p>
```

Comment: Doesn't that require editing the HTML? I only control the CSS of the file, so I don't know if that would work. Can I derive a var from the score attribute?

Comment: var is taken from css attribtes its why i have put it into styles, score attribute is not used in this case.